# Excel - Trim the text after it finds combination of Numeric followed by alphabetic character

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How to trim the below text which contains alphanumeric characters and also it has a description.

Example text: BACA-AA01A-withsomediscription,
              BACA-AA01Bwithsomediscription

Every code ends with the combination of Numeric followed by Alphabetic.
"BACA-AA01A","BACA-AA01B". SO I NEED AN EXCEL FORMULA WHERE I CAN TRIM MY TEXT AFTER IT FINDS THE COMBINATION OF NUMBERIC AND ALPHABETIC.

Comment: Is the code always a single char after the number? Is it a fixed length?Could  you just chop out the code by using the Data,Text To Columns command and choosing fixed length?

Comment: I can trim or use LEFT formula if the code ends with the same fixed length but the length of the code is between 9 to 16. and yes it will always end with a single char after the number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function - paste this into a module page and you can use the function in spreadsheets

```
Public Function Leftish(s As String)
'returns first n chars which fit pattern *nn?
Dim x As Long
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim a As String
For x = 1 To Len(s)
    a = a & Mid(s, x, 1)
    If IsNumeric(Right(a, 1)) Then flag = True
    If (flag And Not IsNumeric(Right(a, 1))) Then Exit For
Next x
Leftish = a

End Function
```

Comment: superb man, unbelievable this is what I'm exactly looking for. Thank you. I want to learn VBA after this, could you please suggest me some learning resources or some online course where I can get a strong foundation on VBA?

Comment: The above code is still helping me without any problem, by continuing to the same question can I get the description or whatever it is after the product code into a separate cell next to the product code that your VBA trims as per the above code. An example I have product code "BACA-AA01Bwithsomediscription" and now your VBA code is able to extract "BACA-AA01B" but I also need the next remaining part without space in the beginning if any in the very next column "withsomediscription"

Comment: If you have the above function in cell D1  and the text in C1, then in cell E1 you can use =RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-Len(D1)) to give you the remainder

Answer (score 0):

For this example we use Shee1 and the data apperas in Column A.
Try:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub Test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim WholeString As String, Part1 As String, Part2 As String

   'Use Sheet1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To Lastrow
            'Clean and trim the whole string
            WholeString = Application.Clean(Application.Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value))
            'Get the firts 10 characters because BACA-AA01A & BACA-AA01B has ten characters each
            Part1 = Application.Clean(Application.Trim(Left(WholeString, 10)))
            .Range("B" & i).Value = Part1
            'Get the remain characters
            Part2 = Application.Clean(Application.Trim(Mid(WholeString, 11, Len(WholeString) - 10)))
            .Range("C" & i).Value = Part2
        Next i

    End With

 End Sub
```

Output:

[image]